# How can I retrieve persisted claims from a previous login using a session management technical profile?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm not entirely sure how the DefaultSSOSessionProvider works for managing the internal session. For example, take SM-AAD from the custom policy starter pack. If a user runs through the signup_signin policy for the first time, they should now have an internal B2C session containing any persisted claims. If objectId is a persisted claim, shouldn't it be repopulated before the first orchestration step of the user journey while their session exists? I'm running through the signup_signin policy multiple times, but none of the persisted claims (like objectId or objectIdFromSession) are ever repopulated to the claims bag.

Answer (score 0):

Claims that are persisted in a session management technical profile are automatically repopulated into the user journey during SSO when the journey executes a technical profile that includes that particular session management technical profile.

Claims that are output in a session management technical profile are automatically populated into the user journey during SSO when the journey executes a technical profile that includes that particular session management technical profile. So these output claims are only present in the claimgbag during an SSO auth.

Comment: I'm trying to use SM-AAD to retrieve the objectId of the user from a different policy after they have signed in using the default signup_signin policy. I can't seem to retrieve the object ID despite including SM-AAD in a technical profile.